# C# how to append a custom Xml Declaration to the Root Element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm really just trying to create a serialize XML document for simple configuration processing. From POCO object to XML string.

What I have done so far!

```
var qbReq = new Qbxml
{
    QbxmlMsgRq = new QbxmlMsgRq
    {
        OnError = "continueOnError",
        CustomerQueryRq = new CustomerQueryRq
        {
            RequestId = 1
        }
    }
};

var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Qbxml));
using var sww = new StringWriter();
using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
serializer.Serialize(writer, qbReq, xns);
var xml = sww.ToString();
```

And My POCO object!

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="CustomerQueryRq")]
public class CustomerQueryRq 
{ 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="requestID")]
    public int RequestId { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="QBXMLMsgsRq")]
public class QbxmlMsgRq 
{ 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="CustomerQueryRq")] 
    public CustomerQueryRq CustomerQueryRq { get; set; } 

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="onError")] 
    public string OnError { get; set; } 
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="QBXML")]
public class Qbxml 
{ 

    [XmlElement(ElementName="QBXMLMsgsRq")] 
    public QbxmlMsgRq QbxmlMsgRq { get; set; } 
}
```

What I am getting so far!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
         <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1" />
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

What is my expectation!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
         <CustomerQueryRq requestID="1" />
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

What is missing is?

```
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
```

I have gone through some Stackoverflow links and MS documentation. But haven't been able to figure out how to add a customs declaration.

[MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createxmldeclaration?view=net-5.0)
[Previous Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839630/how-to-get-xml-with-header-xml-version-1-0)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461117/11683?

Comment: `XmlDeclaration` represents the XML declaration node `<?xml version='1.0'...?>.` You can't add custom declaration via `CreateXmlDeclaration` method. BTW: such of requirement should be done via Envelope. In other words, your structure should be "packed" into Envelope with custom definitions, such as version, etc.